# Lock an Axis - Curve Modifier

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

So I have a curve and an object moving along the curve using the curve modifier. My question is can I lock an axis so the object will, for example, only move back and forth on the x axis, or y axis, or the z axis?

[image: Here's a simple example]

Comment: You can add another constraint to the stack, like Limit Location and enable its checkbox "Minimum.." by some axis. The downside is that you will need to enter global coordinates for minimum and that limiting won't be quite flexible.

Comment: Thank you! that's exactly what I needed! 

Edit: if you want to, it'd be great if you could answer the question so I can accept the answer and people can see it for future reference. Otherwise, I'll just answer it.

Comment: actually now that I check again, this only works with the follow path constraint but still good!

Comment: I think answer it with what worked for you, but please include some screenshots and short description of what you did and how.

Comment: alright, I'll do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so with some help from [Mr Zak](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/1245/mr-zak), I found the solution to this problem.

So for anyone wondering, I was needing this for a 3D printing type animation.
Anyway, start with your curve and some objects.

[image]

Add the "Follow Path" constraint and in select your curve for the target.
To animate, go to your first frame and keyframe the "Offset:" to -100 (this may be different for some curves but this works for most). Then go to the last frame and keyframe the "Offset:" to 0 (if these values don't work, just drag the offset value until it looks right).

The cubish object in the picture just follows around the curve (for you 3D printers, it's the extruder).

The two cylinders just move forward and back with the cube (this just achieves the look of the cube moving left and right and the bars moving forward and back).

For the object you want moving only on one axis, do the same as before but add a "Limit Location" constraint after the "Follow Path" constraint.

[image]

If you want it on one axis, check the "Minimum" and "Maximum" boxes for the desired axis. If you follow the instructions up to this point, then it won't change it's position on that axis while it moves. Here's a gif showing what mine looks like

[image]